# Implementing POST and PUT request with Express on server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What is the difference in PUT and POST implementation in Node.js, Express implementation (server-side):

I mean:

```
app.put(function (req, res) {
//implementation

})

app.post(function (req, res) {
//implementation

})
```

**I am asking for a illustrative example with POST and PUT. An example to show when to use POST but not PUT and vice versa**

Comment: `put` and `post` are different http verbs. Can you clarify what exactly you're asking?

Comment: I am asking for a illustrative example with POST and PUT. An example to show when to use POST but not PUT and vice versa

Comment: This is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest